# Placement of warning within a trade flow

Tags: user-expectation, user-centered-design, error-message, warnings, flow

We need to warn customers who are about to trade a stock that it is currently suspended (https://www.nasdaq.com/glossary/s/suspended-trading). What's the best place and way to notify the customers about it? I was thinking of three possible ways (or a combination of few):

1. Have a short message above 'Buy/Sell' button with a link to more information about the status of this stock
2. Have a separate screen that appears when customer clicks 'Buy/Sell' that explains the status of the stock before customer can 'Continue' to Trade screen.
3. Have a warning message with an explanation in the Trade screen (after customer clicks 'Buy/Sell')

In all scenarios, the customer can still perform a trade but we need to notify them (and possibly provide a checkbox for a consent acknowledging the status) before they continue.

Hopefully that's enough information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**I would prefer option 1.**

It is clear beforehand what the status of the stock is and the investor can decide whether she wants to take the risk of a trade. It is also transparent and shows that you are not afraid of people calling you out for suspended stocks and that you do not hide it somewhere.

**Option 2&3:** They are similar in that they appear after the Buy/Sell. Why is this problematic? Picture this, you want to buy an item online. After clicking "Add it to card" the web shop tells you that as the item is out of stock it may take 2-3 weeks longer to deliver. You would want to know this beforehand, wouldn't you?

**Proposal for UI**
[image]

Comment: Yes, it makes sense and I would agree with the approach of being transparent beforehand. However, what if the customer consent is required in a form of checkbox that he/she agrees to trade a suspended stock? It should happen within Trade screen or in a separate screen to bring more attention? I imagine not a lot of people read through consent texts before checking the box..

Comment: I added a proposal for a layout to the answer. I would add a small warning with a checkbox that enables the Buy/Sell button.

Answer (score 0):

Notifications and messaging within an application should be designed so that it can be applied consistently and effectively to allow the users to read and act on the message.

For example, if you look at the StackOverflow Design System Stacks, you'll find [how they manage notices to the users in their component library](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/notices/).

> Notices deliver System and Engagement messaging, informing the user
> about product or account statuses and related actions.

So they have at least defined two different categories of messages, which will involve at least two different types of components.

- Inline notices that is inserted into the content of the page (this can be at the top if it is really important, or at the section of the page where the information is relevant
- Toast notices that pops up and can have dismissible or timed behaviour for persistence